# how to implement validation in real time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have implemented validation for fundtransfer in jsfiddle.
it works fine but i validation completed in my fiddle but still there is one problem. i want that if user not inserting any value and go for a next textbox by pressing tab then he or she can be see error message.how to do this

my jquery code is here

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#text10").keyup(function(){
        $("#text10").blur();
        $("#text10").focus();
    });
    $("#text10").change(function(){
        var name = $('#text10').val();
        var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;   
        var exp =/^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
        var specialChars = /[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/]/;

        if (name == "" || name == " " )
        {
            //  alert('All Boxes have ents.');
            $("#equal").show();
            $("#equal label").html("name doesn't empty"); 
        }

        $("#text11").keyup(function(){
            $("#text11").blur();
            $("#text11").focus();
        });
        $("#text11").change(function(){
            var name = $('#text11').val();
            var specialChars = "<>@!#$%^&*()_+[]{}?:;|'\"\\,./~`-=";

            if (name == "" || name == " " )
            {
                //  alert('All Boxes have elements.');
                $("#equal1").show();
                $("#equal1 label").html("Please enter Address");
            }
```

my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hirenwebdp/xhF3j/53/)

Comment: why don't you just use the [jquery validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Comment: or [jQuery validationEngine](http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/)

Comment: Please reduce your code to highlight the issue in it's simplest form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plz try it , i was prepare an example on your requirement

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).on('keydown', 'input.text', function(e) { 
         var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 

                 if (keyCode == 9) { 
                     if($(".text").val()==""||$(".text").val()==null)
                  {
                 $(this).css("borderColor","#FF0000")
                 $("#error").text("plz fill it first");
                  }

                  }
 });
</script>
<input type="text" value="" class="text">
<input type="text" value="" class="text" >
<p id="error"></P>
```

Answer (score 1):

use "focus" and "blur" event of j query, if user pressing text box without inserting any value, then he or she can be see error message.

For any query feel free for ask.

Comment: i had already use that dear.please check what i have made wrong

Comment: Your triggering blur and focus but not attaching any events to it?